# How to create a @RequestMapping that accepts no request parameters Spring

Tags: java, spring

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<Object> list(WebRequest req) {
```

I have this code in my application, I want to subclass the class that has this method and create a new method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<Object> list(WebRequest req, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false", required= true) String includehardcoded) {
```

Now I am getting: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found` when my beans are created. I get that the declaration is ambigous but is there any way to make the method in the parent class accept no request parameters at all?

This works:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params="!includehardcoded")
public HttpEntity<Object> list(WebRequest req) {
```

but then it is an ugly hack that uses information from the subclass in the parent class (and I inherit this parent class multiple times).

Comment: You should be doing it the other way around. Create a method that expects the parameter... so for the subclass add `params="includehardcoded"`. Also your `@RequestParam` shouldn't have a default value if it is required, setting a default value implicitly disables required.

Comment: @M.Deinum I only added the `required` because I was trying to get it to work, in my case I don't care which method it uses if the `includehardcoded` parameter is not set because both will return the same value in that case. I did not understand what you said about doing it the other way around...

Comment: It is just as I said you want the one with the parameter invoked only if the parameter is available so instead of adding an exclusion to the default method add an inclusion to the subclass method.